# How to remove hash tag from the URL for a single page in Angular js

Tags: html, angularjs, url

I want to remove hash tag (#) from the URL for a single page in angular js.
Here is my code:

```
angular.config(['$routeSegmentProvider','$locationProvider'
function ($routeSegmentProvider,locationProvider) {
    $routeSegmentProvider
        .when('/test', 'sample')
        .segment('sample', {
            templateUrl: 'test/sample.html',                
        });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);           
    }
]);
```

When I tried with this code, I got my output as,
    http://example.com/#%2Ftest%2F

I need output like below
    http://example.com/test

Can anyone help me to find out what went wrong with my code?

Comment: What plugin have you used for routing?

Comment: @ganesh Angular route segment

Comment: @Sudha, Use this ( **$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);** ) line instead of yours and **<base />** tag is required for html5Mode.

Comment: This may help https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

Comment: Hi Natiq, I tried with what you said but still am getting the same output.

Comment: A hashtag is a means of indicating that a term should be hyperlinked to a search engine on social media networks. It gets the name because it it uses a hash character to prefix it. Please don’t confuse other uses of the hash character with hashtags.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `<base href="/">` right after your `<meta>` tags in your index.html file.

Comment: Hi, i cannot edit html. i need to change url from angular routeprovider itself